# Modeling stitching - issues

Tags: modeling

Trying to model stitches around some car seats and can't seem to make sense of what's happening. After trying to find the solution here and on Youtube, I'm defeated!  I'm using an array and curve modifier

It seems to go in some random place and doesn't follow the curve at all, also it gets distorted like crazy.  I've attached some references while trying both on the actual seat, and just a curve I drew in case the one I had was the issue.

On the first image, the stitching is really distorted and should be facing up and not to the side.  The second is the modeled stitch.  The third is showing the seat I'd like it to follow and where it actually ends up.

Edit: After a while of trying I managed to get close, but it's still not in the right place, I attached a screenshot at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I found out my problem was the stitch wasn't modeled in the world origin. Moving it there and then playing around with the orientation got it to work pretty well.

I'm not sure if there's a way to select multiple curves (or have multiple curves in the same object). That didn't work for me and I had to copy each stitch and assign it to an individual curve as it's own object.
[image]